# Subquery issue Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have this code which returns 0 rows.

```
sel count(loan_id) from table1
where to_number(current_arrears) <= 0
having count(*) in (
 sel count(sub_loan_id) from table1
 where to_number(current_arrears) > 0
)
```

I need it to return a single row with a value of 0 (count = 0). So I did this:

```
sel count(*) from(
 sel count(loan_id) from table1
 where to_number(current_arrears) <= 0
 having count(*) in (
  sel count(sub_loan_id) from table1
  where to_number(current_arrears) > 0
 )
) as A;
```

But I get this error message:

> All expressions in a derived table must have an explicit name.

I just need it to return a count of 0. Please help.

Found a solution in case someone needs it (applied alias to all counts):

```
sel count(*) as c from(
 sel count(loan_id) as c1 from table1
 where to_number(current_arrears) <= 0
 having count(*) in (
  sel count(sub_loan_id) as c2 from table1
  where to_number(current_arrears) > 0
 )
) as A;
```

Cheers!

Comment: But what are you trying to do? A [mcve] would make it easier to assist you!

Comment: Hi jarlh, I'm trying to get a single value by aggregation (count). That's why I wrapped first code snippet in a subquery.

Comment: A [mcve] would still make things clearer. Make it easy to assist you!

Comment: You just need `as c1` because this is in a Derived Table.

Comment: That's actually true, just tried it and it worked. Thanks @dnoeth